# Western Digital Blue High Pitch Noise Spinning Down

Tags: hard-drive

I picked up a Western Digital Blue 1TB WD10EZEX last week and noticed that when spinning down it makes a really high pitched noise for about 9 seconds whenever it spins down or goes idle that I can hear 10 feet away clearly and I just unplugged it because its too loud. Someone told me a while ago that all the blues make that noise but I got a hold of another WD10EZEX and its not making that noise at all. I checked it with Western Digital tools though and it passes their tests.

This is the spin up and spin down of the hard drive about a 5 inches away here.
https://soundcloud.com/user-285338497/wd-blue-spinup-spindown

I'm wondering If I should return it and get it replaced.

Thanks

Comment: If it is a new drive and you're concerned, you should contact WD about replacement. I've heard drives whine and I've heard drives not whine. Most whines didn't indicate failure.

Answer (score 2):

I've opened up many harddisks in my life for the sake of destroying them (or at least make sure the data on it cannot be recovered in any way)

Some harddisks have certain pads that are normally used to reduce sounds and vibrations. It sounds like one of these pads got loose and is floating around in the drive.

I would definitely try and get the drive replaced through RMA if possible.

Tools won't find this as its not a software but mechanical problem, one that simply won't occur in 99.9% of the cases.